# Non-linear ODE $y y'' = A/x^2$ approximate solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently stuck on approximating a solution to a non-linear ODE. I've searched high and low on this site for general methods for approximating non-linear ODE's of the type $$y(x)y''(x) = \frac{A}{x^2}, x > 0, A \in \mathbb{R}$$ with no luck. If you have a link in mind to a previously asked question regarding this, I'd be glad to see it.

It could be that there is something entirely trivial that I am missing in approximating a solution to this equation! My experience with non-linear ODEs is quite limited.

So this question is about finding an approximate solution to the above-mentioned non-linear ODE with BCs $y(0)=\alpha, y'(\infty)=0$, $\alpha \in [0,\pi/2]$. Any ideas? I'd love to hear your thoughts.

The above equation follows by letting $u(x)=xy(x)$ in the equation $$u'''=A/u^2$$ with BCs $u(0)=\varepsilon, u'(0)=\alpha, u''(\infty)=0$ with $\varepsilon \ll 1$ (a small number) and using that $y'(x)$ is small so that $u'=y+xy'=y$ and $u''=y',u'''=y''$.

Comment: How do you go from a third order to a second order equation without an additional integration constant? Could you further explain how to go from $u$ to $y$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @LutzL. The BCs on $u$ are $u(0)=0, u'(0)=\alpha,u''(\infty)=0$, not entirely sure how the first BC translates to a BC on $y$

Comment: That seems impossible from the start, in $u^2u'''=A$ the condition $u(0)=0$ implies $A=0$.

Comment: @LutzL You're right! How silly. $u(0)$ really just has to be a small value, say $u(0)=\varepsilon \ll 1$, I've updated the post.

Comment: your equation is scale invariant under $x\to \lambda x$, so you can seek a solution of the form $y(x)=z(\ln x)$.  The resulting equation for $z(t)$ will be autonomous (no explicit $t$ dependence), so you can substitute $u(z)=z'(t)$ to reduce the order by 1.

Comment: @user254433 Ahh, I see. Hmm, how does the last substitution $u(z)=z'(t)$ reduce the order by 1?

Comment: take the 2nd order equation $y''(t)=y(t)y'(t)$ as an example.  Letting $y'(t)=u(y)$ gives $y''(t)=d(u(y))/dt=u'(y)y'(t)=u(y)u'(y)$, so the equation becomes $u(y)u'(y)=y u(y)$, which is a first order equation.  After deducing $u(y)=y^2/2+c$, you can then return to $y'(t)=u(y)$ to solve for $y(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{A}{x^2} \tag 1$$
Change of variable : $\quad x=e^t \quad;\quad\frac{dt}{dx}=e^{-t}.\quad$ [Eventually, for more generality $x=c\,e^t$, any $c$]

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=e^{-t}\frac{dy}{dt}$

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-t}\frac{dy}{dt}\right)e^{-t}= \left(\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac{dy}{dt}\right)e^{-2t}$
$$y\left(\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac{dy}{dt}\right)e^{-2t}=\frac{A}{x^2}=Ae^{-2t}$$
$$y\left(\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac{dy}{dt}\right)=A$$

This is an autonomous ODE. Change of function : $\quad \frac{dy}{dt}=X(y)$

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac{dX}{dt}=\frac{dX}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}=X\frac{dX}{dy}$
$$y\left(X\frac{dX}{dy}-X\right)=A$$

$$\left(\frac{dX}{dy}-1\right)X(y)=\frac{A}{y}$$

The ODE has been reduced of the first order. Solving it leads to the solution on the implicit form :
$$\frac{2A}{y}\exp\left(-\frac{(X-y)^2}{2A}\right)+\sqrt{2\pi}\text{ erfi}\left(\frac{X-y}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)=C$$
The most likely, there is no closed form for the function $X(y)$.

As a consequence, one cannot come back to $t(y)=\int \frac{dy}{X(y)}$, then to the inverse function $y(t)$ and finally to $y(x)$.

This draw to use numerical methods to solve Eq.$(1)$ instead of looking for an exact analytic method.

For approximate solution, it is of interest to first change of function : $\quad y(x)=\sqrt{A}\:Y(x)$
$$Y\,Y''=\frac{1}{x^2}$$
This is an ODE without parameter, which reduces a lot the number of cases to study. Only the initial conditions have to be taken into account. For example : http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+y%27%27%3D1%2Fx%5E2

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the very detailed and nicely written explanation @JJacquelin. I love all the well-chosen change of variables and change of functions that you are using to get the ODE to look in a way that can be made sense of. I'll keep plugging away and hopefully I'll be able to do similar analyses in the future!